# (list lambda lambda)

Tags: syntax, scheme

What 'kind of thing' will I get if I do this?

```
(car (list lambda lambda))
```

I thought I'd get `lambda` back, which means I could do

```
(define my_lambda (car (list lambda lambda)))
(define foo (my_lambda (n) (+ n n)))
```

But that didn't work!
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lambda` is a special form (meaning: standard evaluation rules don't apply to it), part of the core primitives of the language and is *not* a symbol or other kind of value that can be assigned to a variable.

Answering your question, the "kind of thing" that you'll get after evaluating the expression `(list lambda)` will depend on the Scheme interpreter that you're using, but more often than not you'll get an error. For instance, DrRacket complains like this:

```
lambda: bad syntax in: lambda
```

Answer (score 2):

In some sense, `lambda` doesn't exist at runtime (sure, the *functions* created by lambda statements exist, but that's a different matter; they aren't `lambda` itself).

The reason for this is that the lambda statement manipulates other things that don't exist at runtime; in particular, it changes the meaning of variable names (in your example, `n`).

To answer your question about what kind of thing `lambda` is, the usual answer is "syntax". Fortunately, Scheme provides a mechanism to abstract over syntax: macros. Macros can abstract over compile-time-only entities, like variable names and lambdas and other macros. So, you could write (in the Racket REPL, in this case):

```lisp
> (define-syntax-rule (mylambda (x ...) body)
    (lambda (x ...) body))
> (define foo (mylambda (n) (+ n n)))
> (foo 71)
142
```

There are multiple systems for defining Scheme macros; the `syntax-rules` system uses `...`s in an unusual, but ultimately pretty intuitive fashion. It is also possible to define macros by writing Scheme code that emits Scheme, which involves a little more complication.